Relationship between the spectra of the zero and first Hodge Laplacian on 2 dimensional manifolds.
Considering an oriented and compact surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I would like to know if there exisits a particular relationship between the spectrum of the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta_0 = - \star_2d_1\star_1d_0$ and the spectrum of the first Hodge Laplacian $\Delta_1 = -\star_1d_0\star_2d_1 - d_0\star_2d_1\star_1$. So far I know that:

The kernels of $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_1$ may have different dimension deppending on the genus and the number of connected components.
If $g$ and $f$ are eigenfunctions of $\Delta_0$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $d_0f+\star_1d_0g$ is an eigenform of $\Delta_1$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.
$\Delta_2 = - d_1\star_1d_0\star_2$ and $\Delta_0$ are isospectral.

About the second bullet point, I would like to know whether $d_0f+\star_1d_0g\neq 0$ or not necessarily. Does $\lambda$ being an eigenvalue of $\Delta_1$ imply that it is also an eigenvalue of $\Delta_0$? If $\lambda\neq 0 $ is an eigenvalue of both $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta_1$, do the corresponding eigenspaces have same dimension?
Thanks!
